# Redirect issue in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4 and i want to add a `filter` after route logic. so the filter is executed but redirect instruction is not executed `return Redirect::to($pool->url . '/share')->with('poolURL' ,URL::to($pool->url));`

This the code :

```
   if(Session::has('pool')){

    $entry = Session::get('pool');

    // Update pool userId

    $entry['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

    $pool = Pool::create($entry);

        // Update pool URL
      $pool->url = Auth::user()->username
       . '/pool/'
       . Str::slug($pool->beneficiary)
       . '/'
       . $pool->id;

        // Update and redirect to Share page
       if($pool->save())
       {
       return Redirect::to($pool->url . '/share')->with('poolURL' ,URL::to($pool->url));
       }

    }
```

Comment: You cannot redirect in an after filter because the route has been executed and the response has already been sent to the browser. That's why in an after filter you have access to $response.

Comment: Which response do you mean in this case?

Comment: Then is there any way to execute a code juste before `return` in route logic?

Comment: The routes response. Off course there is. Why don't you do it in the controller? Can you describe what are you trying to do?

Comment: `The routes response.`, if I understood you mean `return` statment. if correct , I tried to remove `return` in route and leave just `return` in filter, to make just one response  , but didn't work anyway.

Comment: Ok, I saved data in `Session` and I redirect user to login page, then after auth, i should save session data in the database. The problem here is that I want to keep the saving code out of UserController and making it reusable in other request like signup.
it's make sense for you ? Thanks

Comment: Another way i tried is : add method in a `BaseController` and call it for every Login and Signup post but also didn't work .

Comment: In case you want to reuse the functionality, you have to get it out of your controller. Why don't you create another class that will be responsible for this functionality and inject it via dependency injection in every controller that you need it?